# HTML Label float passed Checkbox on left

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, label

I have a checkbox and a label, and while the label is set after the checkbox, it appears before it when the page is in view.

What could be the problem?

```
<input name="signed" id="fd_supplier_contract_signed" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label for="fd_supplier_contract_signed">Signed:</label>
```

IMAGE:

[image]

Comment: FYI - The only reason I had the link in is because they wouldn't let me post an image cuz I don't have 10 q's in.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data in the image is lined up, you have styles that are controlling the positioning of the elements.

How to fix it totally depends upon what the styles are doing for the label elements and the input/checkbox elements.

Comment: They are both relative element, that are floating and the checkbox is even cleared left.